# Show PDF saved as blob in oracle db in Birt report

Tags: birt

I am designing a Birt report where we have a requirement of showing PDF which is saved as Blob in oracle DB. What tried to add it as dynamic image in my table column of report. But when i generate report i get output in some bytes format not as pdf. Is it possible to show a pdf in report which is saved as blob in DB table.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT doesn't recognize PDF as an image format probably.

I don't think this is supported.

BTW, the BIRT ROM documentation does not say anything about which formats *are* supported.

Handling PDF like an image seems weird, anyway. A PDF can have multiple pages.
In our application, we use a post-processing tool (you could use iText for this) to append the PDF to the BIRT-generated PDF. However, this approach depends on the way you have BIRT integrated into your application.
For example, it will probably not work with the sample WebViewer.